# Adding send and microphone buttons to a bot

Tags: reactjs, botframework

I'm using reactjs to build a web chat, I'm trying to display microphone and send buttons at the same time but it doesn't work, Only one of them disply, I heard that there's a limitation for doing this but I don't think so, Is there any suggestions?

Comment: can you provide some code??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Web Chat is not designed for utilizing both the `send` button and the `speak` button, simultaneously. That is to say, technically, you can get both to display however if speech is enabled, then the `send` button will not respond.

This is because certain `send` elements and classes are replaced when `speak` is enabled. As such, even though the `send` button can be hacked back into Web Chat, it won't respond.

If you feel this would be a good feature for Web Chat to include, I would suggest you present it as a feature request [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Enhancement%2C+Pending%2C+customer-reported%2C+Bot+Services&template=feature_request.md&title=).

Hope of help!